# Does the code for AddThis button need to have the pubid string if analytics are not being tracked?

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, addthis

I am writing an asp.net server control to render the addthis buttons in various projects.

Notice the pubid string below. With analytics enabled that string is the userid. For the server control i will retreive the id from appSettings. How important is that string if analytics are not being tracked? If that string is left off (everything after the js extension of the url) will addthis still work correctly? Since a unique string is generated for each site even if there is no account i thought it must have some importance. So bottom line questions is will AddThis work correctly if the pubid is left off if no analytics arebing followed? Thanks...

```
 <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4ee96d151f836a06"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the profile ID isn't necessary if you're not collecting analytics. However, users without a profile ID won't be able to send shares via email as a spam fighting measure.